# Unable to use c:AuraPubSub

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/all-about-custom-lightning-page-templates.html) post to create a collapsible template for a console application. Everything worked fine untill I added a lightning datatable to the picture. The page loads fine, collapses fine but it now stays expanded once expand button is clicked.

To overcome this issue, I am planning to re-render(hide and show) the datatable region. To achieve this, I need to fire an event(from Aura) when the button is clicked and handle it in LWC. So I started adding in the pubsub code samples given in [recipe repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/aura/auraPubsubPublisher).

You may notice the ugly scrollbars here.

[image]

However, the moment I add `<c:auraPubsub aura:id="pubsub" />` to my aura component, it throws the below error:

> Looks like there's a problem.
>
> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details.

Console also shows below:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: This kind of sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Have you tried asking a question about your X, the table that doesn't work? While I agree that it'd be nice to figure out this internal error, perhaps a different approach might solve your problem better.

Comment: Thank you. I wrapped the auraPubSub component and the button to another component and used it in the template and the issue is resolved now. But it felt like a hack and not the recommended approach. What do you think?? Should I post it as the solution for everyone else and close off the thread or keep it open for further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling with the same issue, as a workaround, I wrapped the auraPubSub component and the button to another aura component and used it in the template to resolve the issue.